# Delphi RESTClient - Using a Tfrm_OAuthWebForm

Tags: delphi, oauth-2.0, rest-client

I'm trying the:-

1. Request an OAuth 2.0 authorisation code with the required scope

tutorial from:- 
https://developer.service.hmrc.gov.uk/api-documentation/docs/tutorials

and I'm using Delphi 10.1 with RESTClient and a Tfrm_OAuthWebForm.

The example says "The user will be redirected to the HMRC login screen. When they've submitted their credentials, they'll be asked to authorise your application to access the requested scope."

I'm getting the HMRC login page, just a:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ7zj.png)
I'm only at the first stage:-

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnHello_User_RESTClient_Self_Bind_Test_1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
LURL: string;
wv: Tfrm_OAuthWebForm;
LToken: string;
begin
  /// step #1: get the auth-code
  LURL := 'https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/oauth/authorize';
  LURL := LURL + '?client_id=' + URIEncode (eHello_User_Client_ID.Text);
  LURL := LURL + '&scope=hello';
  LURL := LURL + '&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/redirect'
  LURL := LURL + '&response_type=code'

  // optional
  // LURL := LURL + '&login_hint=' + URIEncode('user@example.com');

  Add_To_Memo(LURL, False{Clear_Memo});

  wv := Tfrm_OAuthWebForm.Create(self);
  try
    wv.OnTitleChanged := self.OAuth2Authenticator1_Hello_User_BrowserTitleChanged;
    wv.ShowModalWithURL(LURL);
  finally
    wv.Release;
  end;
end;
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Hope that makes sense.

tia

Answer (score 0):

After a quick read of the HMRC instructions, this may not work in the context you are trying to use.  Their intent is for the call to pull their credential page to be displayed and on successful authentication they want to redirect back to your web server application at "https://www.example.com/redirect" as in their example with the auth token in the query string.  You could with some significant effort detect the URL load in your Tfrm_OAuthWebForm and extract the token, but not an easy step.

Comment: Hi Randy Thanks for the replay. The problem was I hadn't added the redirect url to the HMRC Hub application. This was brought to my attention from another web site.